# How can I open an mp3 file using Java/Groovy via a URL?

Tags: groovy, mp3

Does anyone have any useful advice/links to information about working with mp3 files in Groovy.  I appreciate that this is just the same as working with Java libs, but wanted a simple solution to this problem:

- I want to load an mp3 via a URL and interrogate it.
- I'd like to test whether it exists and pull out the title, artist and default image if it's there.

Any help appreciated.  Thanks.

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try an ID3 library? I haven't tried [this one from Sourceforge](http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/) but it looks like the right thing.